Audio streaming
I'm trying to send audio in one way from client mic to server speaker, I tried using tcp socket and use these codes.
This for client side:
import socket
import sounddevice as sd
import numpy as np
import threading
import time

# Sender settings
HOST = "server ip"  # Server IP address
PORT = 6000  # Server port

# Adjust buffer sizes
BUFFER_SIZE = 8192*4 # Match the server's BLOCK_SIZE

# Create a socket for communication
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect((HOST, PORT))
print(f"Connected to server at {HOST}:{PORT}")

ack_received = False  # Flag to track acknowledgment
mic_enabled = False  # Flag to track microphone status

def audio_callback(indata, frames, time, status):
    global ack_received
    if status:
        print(f"Error in audio stream: {status}")
    if mic_enabled and ack_received:
        #print(f"Sending data: {len(indata.tobytes())} bytes")  # Debug
        client_socket.sendall(indata.tobytes())

def receive_ack():
    global ack_received
    while True:
        try:
            data = client_socket.recv(1024)  # Receive acknowledgment from server
            if data == b'ACK':
                ack_received = True  # Set acknowledgment flag
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error receiving acknowledgment: {e}")
            break

def handle_input():
    global mic_enabled
    while True:
        command = input("Press '1' to enable mic, '0' to disable mic: ")
        if command == '1':
            mic_enabled = True
            client_socket.sendall(b'1')  # Notify the server to expect audio data
        elif command == '0':
            mic_enabled = False

# Start a thread to receive acknowledgments from the server
ack_thread = threading.Thread(target=receive_ack)
ack_thread.daemon = True  # Daemonize the thread so it terminates with the main thread
ack_thread.start()

# Start a thread to handle user input
input_thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_input)
input_thread.daemon = True  # Daemonize the thread so it terminates with the main thread
input_thread.start()

with sd.InputStream(callback=audio_callback, blocksize=BUFFER_SIZE, latency='low', channels=1):
    print("Sending audio to server. Press Ctrl+C to stop.")
    try:
        while True:
            if ack_received and mic_enabled:
                time.sleep(0.01)  # Add a small delay to reduce CPU usage
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Exiting...")
        client_socket.close()  # Close the socket on client exit

This is for the server:
import time
import threading
import sounddevice as sd
import numpy as np

def audio_callback(outdata, frames, time, status, conn):
    global audio_running
    with audio_running_lock:
        if not audio_running:
            return
    if status:
        print(f"Error in audio stream: {status}")
        if status.output_underflow:
            print("Output underflow occurred. Consider adjusting buffer sizes or optimizing performance.")
    try:
        data = conn.recv(outdata.nbytes)
        #print(f"Received data: {len(data)} bytes")  # Debug
        if len(data) == 0:
            print("No data received.")
            outdata.fill(0)  # Fill output buffer with zeros (silence)
            return
        data_array = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=outdata.dtype)
        data_array_copy = data_array.copy()  # Create a copy to ensure ownership of data
        data_array_copy.resize((frames, outdata.shape[1]))
        outdata[:, :] = data_array_copy  # Copy processed data to output buffer
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error processing audio data: {e}")

def handle_client_commands(conn):
    global audio_running
    while True:
        try:
            command = conn.recv(1024)
            if command == b'1':
                conn.sendall(b'ACK')
                with audio_running_lock:
                    audio_running = True  # Enable the speaker
            elif command == b'0':
                with audio_running_lock:
                    audio_running = False  # Disable the speaker
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error receiving command: {e}")
            break

def start_socket(HOST, PORT):
    global audio_running, audio_running_lock
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
    server_socket.listen(1)
    print(f"Listening on {HOST}:{PORT}...")

    # Accept a client connection
    conn, address = server_socket.accept()
    print(f"Connected to {address}")

    audio_running = True
    audio_running_lock = threading.Lock()
    BLOCK_SIZE = 8192*4  # Increased buffer size

    # Start a thread for handling client commands
    command_thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client_commands, args=(conn,))
    command_thread.start()

    with sd.OutputStream(callback=lambda outdata, frames, time, status: audio_callback(outdata, frames, time, status, conn),
                          blocksize=BLOCK_SIZE, channels=1):
        print("Receiving audio from client. Press Ctrl+C to stop.")
        while True:
            try:
                time.sleep(0.1)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                print("Stopping server...")
                break

    # Clean up
    command_thread.join()
    server_socket.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_socket("server ip", 6000)

I have some interruption and echo which means audio not clear when applied server code on linux and client code on windows.

Is there any suggestion to solve it ?
Is there any another efficient and more professional way to do same "stream audio over local network", with less latency, low load on network?

Handle my case, in my codes and if there's any suggestion to achieve same task with professional way

You are assuming TCP is message-based.  It is a byte stream.  Do not assume .recv(n) will receive exactly n bytes.  It can receive 1-n bytes or 0 on socket close.  Check the return value and keep receiving until you have the expected number of bytes for a message.  This also means you need a protocol for your byte stream to determine a complete message.  See this answer for an example.
